# kubectl apply vs kubernetes deployment - Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I am trying to use [Kubernetes Deployment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/deployment.html) , i would like to know whether this is same as `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` or does this wait for the deployments to be up and running . because when i used `kubernetes deployment` to create a basic pod which i know will not work, i got this error

`Error: Waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...`

Is this just giving me the error from `kubernetes` or the entire `terraform` script fails because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/deployment.html)

> A Deployment ensures that a specified number of pod “replicas” are running at any one time. In other words, a Deployment makes sure that a pod or homogeneous set of pods are always up and available. If there are too many pods, it will kill some. If there are too few, the Deployment will start more.

So, It will wait to ensure number of expected replicas are up

Comment: oh oh, so it is better to use `kubectl apply` if we want to just apply the files?

Comment: I think so @doc_noob.